# Error : Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android, comparator

I know there are a lot of questions related to this topic, but I can't fully understand what is causing this error

```
 Collections.sort(noteList,new Comparator<ClassNote>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(ClassNote b, ClassNote a) {
           DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd HH:mm", Locale.US);
           try {
               Date date2 = formatter.parse(b.getCallDate());
               Date date1 = formatter.parse(a.getCallDate());
               if ( date1 == null ) {
                   if ( date2 == null) {
                       return 0;
                   }
                   return 1;
               }
               if ( date2 == null ) {
                   return -1;
               }
               return date2.compareTo(date1);
           } catch (ParseException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return 1;
           }
        }
    });
```

Does anyone know why it does not work and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any `ParseException`?  Did you check logcat?  I don't know what `printStackTrace` does on Android.  If you get any parse exceptions, then your comparison function is definitely wrong, but first I'd need to know whether you had any.  If not, I don't see anything wrong with the comparison function.

Comment: Apparantly i was getting ParseExceptions and it seems it messed up the whole sorting algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best plan in cases like this is, instead of focusing on "How do I make my comparison function consistent", ask instead "What do I want a sorted array to look like"?  This is especially important when you're dealing with special cases, as you are.  Once you figure out the correct order, write a comparison function that gives you that order.

Here, you have three categories of `ClassNote` you're dealing with:

1. `ClassNote` objects with valid dates
2. `ClassNote` objects where parsing the date returns `null`
3. `ClassNote` objects where parsing the date throws an exception

Category 1 is easy: you want the objects to be ordered by date.  (You also have to figure what happens when two `ClassNote`s have the same date, but in this case you presumably don't care about the order, which is fine.  In some situations, you may want items with the same date to be sorted by some other field.)

For #2 and #3, where do you want them in the result?  So far, it looks like you want the `null` ones first, but you haven't dealt with the parsing exceptions.  I can see two simple approaches:

1. Treat `null` the same as an exception.  Then all the nulls and exception cases will appear in some order and will be intermingled, but that might be OK.
2. Group them so that the #2 items come first, then #3, then the items with valid dates.  Or the other way: #3, then #2, then valid dates.

Either approach is fine, but you have to make a decision about what you want.

Suppose you go with approach #1.  Now you have to arrange things so that when you compare a #2 item with a #3 item, the result is 0; and when you compare a #2 or #3 item with a #1, the #2 or #3 is always less.  You could modify your existing code

```
 Date date2 = formatter.parse(b.getCallDate());
 Date date1 = formatter.parse(a.getCallDate());
```

to this:

```
 Date date2 = parseOrReturnNull(b.getCallDate());
 Date date1 = parseOrReturnNull(a.getCallDate());
```

where `parseOrReturnNull` is a helper method that uses `formatter.parse()`, catches `ParseException`, and returns *null* if there's an exception.  Now the rest of your logic will ensure that nulls and parse exceptions will be treated the same way for ordering purposes.

If you want to group `null` and exceptions separately, one solution is to add a "category" variable that you apply to each `ClassNote`.  The category would indicate what category the `ClassNote` is in, in the correct order: thus, if you want `null`s first, then exceptions, then valid dates, you could make the category 0 for `null`, 1 for exception, 2 for a valid date.  (Even better, use an `enum`).  Then, for each date, you'd compute both the category and the `date`.  In fact, it might be best to declare a new class:

```
class ComparisonDate {
    int category;  // or enum
    Date date;     // meaningful only if the date is valid
}
```

Use a helper method that takes a `ClassNote` and returns a `ComparisonDate`.  Then you can compare two `ComparisonDate`s with code like this:

```
if (cd1.category != cd2.category) {
    return Integer.compare(cd1.category, cd2.category);
} else if (cd1.category == 2) {    // 2 means they have valid dates
    return cd1.date.compareTo(cd2.date);
} else {        // ComparisonDates are in same category and dates aren't
                // meaningful
    return 0;   // so treat them as equal
}
```

I may have `cd1` and `cd2` switched, but you can work that out.

Comment: Good answer, i actually was getting some parseExceptions and now everything is working with the help of your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you compare two instances of `ClassNote`, `a` and `b`, and parsing one of them will throw an exception:

`compare(a, b)` will return `a` is bigger.

`compare(b, a)` will return `b` is bigger.

The comparison return value is inconsistent.

Comment: do you know how to make comparison return value consistent?

Comment: I guess you should try to parse and catch, separately, for `date1` and `date2`, and then return a value accordingly (unlike now that you return 1 always, regardless of which one failed the parsing).

Comment: Maybe refer to this case the same as it was null.